# ValueError: mmap closed or invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, text-to-speech, gtts

I get the error

> ValueError: mmap closed or invalid

Whenever i try and play audio. the code that seems to be the error is

```
def speak(audioString):
    print(audioString)
    tts = gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
    tts.save("audio.mp3")
    with open("audio.mp3") as f: 
        m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) 

        pygame.mixer.music.load(m) 
        pygame.mixer.music.play() 

m.close()
```

I would like help as i was trying to do textToSpeach and am unable to.

edit: put code spaces  in right place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're closing the mmap `m` as the sound is playing.

```
def speak(audioString):
    print(audioString)
    tts = gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
    tts.save("audio.mp3")
    with open("audio.mp3") as f: 
        m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) 

        pygame.mixer.music.load(m) 
        pygame.mixer.music.play() 

        # wait for audio to finish playing
        while ( pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() ):
            pygame.event.pump()                    # <-- a bit dodgey

        m.close()
```

A quick test is that commenting out the `m.close()` makes it work OK.  You will need to program some other way of handling the loading/playing.  Do you really need the speed optimisation of `mmap` ?

Another approach might be to use the `io` module `StringIO` and never write the audio stream back to disk:

Theoretically something like:

```
import io

...

memfile = io.StringIO()
tts.write_to_fp( memfile )
pygame.mixer.music.load( memfile )   # <<-- NOTE: untested
pygame.mixer.music.play()
# wait for audio to finish playing
while ( pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() ):
    do_something_useful_and_handle_events()
memfile = None
```

But you still probably can't delete `memfile` while the audio is playing.

Comment: i am gonna accept the answer but for the first one it says video system not initialised and the second one says TypeError: 'fp' is not a file-like object or it does not take bytes: string argument expected, got 'bytes'